# Google Tag Assistant says "Tag not fired through GTM"

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

The assistant extension for chrome says "Tag not fired through GTM". However it does not specify anything else.

How can I find out which tag this is as I have quite a few?

Answer (score 1):

Debug it in traditional way - step by step.

Disable triggers in a half of your tags, and check it warning still appears. If yes, do the same with these 50% which still have triggers. If no, You know the problem is with disabled tag, so investigate these 50% which already haven't triggers.

Comment: By disable, you would be delete right? Or is there a hidden disable button I have not found?

Comment: and i pretty much did that and still get this warning

Comment: I ment delete all triggers in specifc tags (but You don't need to delete all triggers at all). BTW. When You disable GTM (delete it from code of your website) do You still have this error?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are in control of the GTM container, I would use the preview mode from GTM ahead of the Tag Assistant extension. It's more descriptive and will tell you exactly which of your tags are and are not firing on any given page. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I used it and it shows "Tags Not Fired On This Page:" in the Tags Summary tab, however it the chrome extension it says "Tag not fired through GTM" and this is new, and I am unsure which tag it is referring too. Any ideas how to pin point it?